# uvcvideo fails to initialize/register entities for Easycamera

Tags: drivers, usb, lenovo

I've had a LENOVO 80VQ/Lenovo ideapad 710S-13IKB with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS installed for almost 2 years.  I don't recall the integrated USB Easycamera ever working and recently it's begun to bother me that I've not found a fix for it. So here's what I've found so far:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5673 IMC Networks

$ lsusb -t 
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

Some output from dmesg when I try `modprobe uvcvideo`

```
  [ 1576.626874] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
  [ 1576.632827] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
  [ 1576.757104] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device EasyCamera (13d3:5673)
  [ 1576.758801] uvcvideo: Failed to initialize entity for entity 6
  [ 1576.758804] uvcvideo: Failed to register entites (-22).
  [ 1576.758822] ------------[ cut here ]------------
  [ 1576.758825] sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/media0'
  [ 1576.758853] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 3977 at /build/linux-vxxS7y/linux-4.15.0/fs/sysfs/dir.c:31 sysfs_warn_dup+0x56/0x70
  [ 1576.758854] Modules linked in: uvcvideo(+) videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core videodev media ccm ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfr  m_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype nf_nat br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs overlay nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common xt_LOG xt_limit xt_tcpudp nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_iprange xt_co  nntrack nf_conntrack libcrc32c iptable_filter bnep arc4 nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi wmi_bmof input_polldev intel_wmi_thunderbolt snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc  _sst_ipc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel intel_rapl snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hd  a_core
...
[ 1576.759130] Call Trace:
...
[ 1576.759490] ---[ end trace 8e6b3e85b1b873ca ]---
  [ 1576.759494] kobject_add_internal failed for media0 with -EEXIST, don't try to register things with the same name in the same directory.
  [ 1576.759503] media: media_devnode_register: cdev_device_add failed
  [ 1576.759797] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
  [ 1576.759799] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
```

That `sysfs` warning about duplicate file name seems relevant as it's in the relevant Easycamera directory. Why does ubscore report uvcvideo as registered even though there seems to be an error?

Can I just delete the media0 directory and try reloading the module? Will that cause any serious problems?

[This email exchange on kernel.org](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/244909/) also seems relevant though I'm not sure.

Any other pointers ? The light on the camera briefly flashes when any application tries to use it. That along with the dmesg error makes me hopeful it's not a hardware malfunction.